# How to see the informations and compiler flags for .o files in linux?

Tags: c++, boost, command, centos

I am using CentOS 6.02 64 bit. I want to see the information and used compiler flags in .o files. Is there any command or way to see that? I have seen the architecture of .a file by using *objdump*. But couldn't seen the information for .o files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to extract the compiler flags from an object file. You can see this by compiling twice with and without some no-op switch like -fverbose-asm (gcc flag which only affects generation of asm) and comparing the objects - they will be identical. There are however some compiler specific extensions which would allow you to insert them during compile e.g. `-frecord-gcc-switches` in newer versions of gcc, which places the flags used in section `.GCC.command.line`. There is also various information inserted by different compilers into the .comment section e.g. my compile with gcc 4.7.2 shows:

```
$objdump -s -j.comment <objfile>

objfile:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 00474343 3a202847 4e552920 342e372e  .GCC: (GNU) 4.7.
 0010 3200                                 2.
```

You can of course get the architecture in the same way as for a .a file, with `objdump -f`.